# How to accept only numeric numbers which has maximum 5 length for an input in Angular?

Tags: angular, maxlength, form-control, angular-validation

I have a input field type **number** and I want to achieve the following scenario.

1. Value length should be less than 5. (Max Length 5)
2. If above condition true only, submit button will enable.

Can someone help me on this?

**.ts**

```
 public searchForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    zip: new FormControl("",[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/), Validators.maxLength(5)]),
  });
```

**.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm">
          <div class = "form-group">
             <input class="form-control form-text-input" type="number" name="zip" 
              formControlName="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Enter a Zip Code" />
          </div>

          <button (click)="myFunction(myModal)" class="btn search-btn mb-1" 
           type="button [disabled]="searchForm.invalid">Search
          </button>
</form>
```

Comment: MaxLength is for text. For numbers you could try Validators.max(99999)

Comment: Hi @MikeOne. Thanks for the explanation. This worked. But still user can enter more than 5 values even though the button is disabled after entering more than 5 values. How to avoid that? User cannot enter more than 5 values in the input field as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `maxLength` is ignored on `<input type="number">`
Read:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-

You can use the `max` Validator to enforce a max length of 5

Hence your .ts will look like this.

```
 public searchForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    zip: new FormControl("",[Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)?$/), Validators.max(99999)]),
  });
```

### Update

Another way to tackle this problem is **IF** `type=number` is not mandatory in your use case, is to remove `type=number`. Then the `Regex` that you are already using will do the validation for you and it will `disable` the button if the user does not input a `number`

Comment: Yes. But in that case even though the button is disabled, it will allow user to at least enter the string/text value. Isn't it?

Comment: @KalanaTebel. Yes. You are correct, the user would be able to enter anything but the button will be `disabled`.

Comment: The provided answer is correct. But is there a way to avoid typing more than 5 numeric values?